# Is Windows SSO possible with Jaas/Krb5LoginModule for Rich Client using Java 7

Tags: client-server, single-sign-on, jaas

It appears that with Java 6 I was able to get the logged in users TGT to generate a Service Ticket; however, when I switch to Java 7 I can no longer get the TGT.  Debug shows "Found no TGT's in LSA".  I am on the same Windows 7 machine and just make the switch within Eclipse.

I have found solutions that others have tried like adding the AllowTgtSessionKey registry, not logging in as local Admin, and disabling UAC.  I have tried all of these and none seem to work and I wouldn't expect a customer to need to do any of these.

So, has anyone implemented this successfully where a user can gain access to a Rich Client just using his already logged in Windows credentials?  I am looking for a pure Java solution for our Rich Client as well as or Web Client.  Is there a better pure Java solution?

Comment: Greg Latham, it's been six years, have you been able to get it to work?  I ask because I now have the same goal with Windows 10/Java 8.  And to add to the list of things to try that don't work: Use latest JCE jars and delete any krb5cc* file.